# Came across this question while practising for Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, probability-limit-theorems

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBoBv.png)
I am confused as to how I should calculate the variance while applying the Central Limit Theorem. Could anyone help me with that?

Comment: Always post your attempt with your question.

Comment: I don't know where to start!